# How to make a 3x2 grid?

Tags: html, css, grid

We have this right now but it has to be like this:

https://postimg.org/image/cw2e572zh/

I'm doing this for school and I can't figure it out the columns keep being 2x3 and not 3x2.

http://prntscr.com/crc7ln

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>  
<meta charset=utf-8>  
<title>HTML CSS exercise - create a CSS Grid</title>  
  
</head>  
<body>  
<div class="container">  
       <div class="row">  
  <div class="col1">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
  <div class="col2">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
  <div class="col3">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
 </div>  
 <div class="row">  
  <div class="col1">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
  <div class="col2">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
  <div class="col3">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
 </div>  
</div>  

</body>  
</html>
```

```css
/* CSS */

.row {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 24%;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
 
.col1 {
   left: 5px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
     
.col2 {
   left: 15px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
     
.col3 {
    left: 25px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
     
body {
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 90%;
    background-color: #e7e7de
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, try to avoid floats as they seem to mess up the way your div's flow sometimes. I've applied the `24%` on the columns rather than the row, also I took out the repetitive declaration of styles. I'd suggest putting the same class on the columns rather than `col1`, `col2` and `col3`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>  
<meta charset=utf-8>  
<title>HTML CSS exercise - create a CSS Grid</title>  
<style>
 .row {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 10px;
 }

 
 .col1, .col2, .col3 {
  left: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 24%;
 }
  
 body {
  border-width: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 90%;
  background-color: #e7e7de
}
</style>  
</head>  
<body>  
<div class="container">  
 <div class="row">  
  <div class="col1">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
  <div class="col2">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
  <div class="col3">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
 </div>  
 <div class="row">  
  <div class="col1">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
  <div class="col2">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
  <div class="col3">  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>  
  </div>  
 </div>  
</div>  

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do realise you have 2 divs with 3 divs in it... Pretty logical you're having 2x3 then and not 3x2, perhaps you want 3 divs with 2 divs in them?

Comment: we fixed it now thanks alot ! (we are beginners in html / css so :P) thanks ! :D

Comment: Great to hear, you're welcome. Since this fixed this for you you should mark my answer as the solution so people know this question has been solved. Good luck :)

Comment: It was a styling problem not a HTML problem, see my answer for solution

Answer (score 0):

Apply these style, reducing the amount of code.

```
<style>  
.row {
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;  
}
.column{
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:24%;
}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

With following structure of HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <p>loren ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p>loren ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p>loren ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <p>loren ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p>loren ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p>loren ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```